# C++ map, find element and insert it into another map (without copying)

Tags: c++, stl

How to correctly find element from source map and insert it into another map?

```
std::map<int, std::shared_prt<Obj>> src_map
std::map<int, std::shared_prt<Obj>> target_map

int key = 6;
auto found_elem = src_map.find(key);

if (found_elem != src_map.end()) {
  if (target_map.find(key) == target_map.end()) {
     target_map.insert(found_elem ); <---- How to correctly insert found element from src_map to target_map
  }
}
```

Comment: There's no way without copying, unless you use something like `std::map<int, std::shared_prt<Obj>> src_map;`.

Comment: "without copying" - so you want to remove it from `src_map`?

Comment: My Obj this is pointer, I dont need to copy object. And i dont need to remove elem from src_map.

Comment: If `Obj` is a pointer type, then you don't need this *question*, much less to copy an object. Or is the "without copying" portion of your title truly not relevant?

Comment: Ok, i have made some correction in code to make it more clear

Comment: Did you try `target_map.insert(std::move(*found_elem))` ?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight that would leave a zombie shared_pointer in the source map

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
  target_map.insert(found_elem);
```

`found_elem` is an iterator, you need to insert the value it refers to:

```
  target_map.insert(*found_elem);
```

Also this could be done more efficiently:

```
  if (target_map.find(key) == target_map.end()) {
     target_map.insert(found_elem);
  }
```

You do the lookup twice.  Once in `find` and again  in `insert`.

It's better to just try to insert it, and if you need to know whether it was inserted check the return value:

```
  auto inserted = target_map.insert(*found_elem);
  // inserted.first is the iterator to the element with the desired key
  // inserted.second is true if a new element was inserted, false if the key already existed
```

Other options for putting it in the map are to find the position where it belongs, then insert at that position if it's not there already:

```
auto lower = target_map.lower_bound(key);
if (lower == target_map.end() || lower->first != key) {
  target_map.insert(lower, *found_elem);
}
```

Another option is:

```
auto& val = target_map[found_elem->first];
if (!val)
  val = found_elem->second;
```

but this is not exactly the same, because if the key already exists in the map with an empty `shared_ptr` as the value then the value will get replaced. Depending whether you can have empty shared_ptr objects in the map that might not be correct for your program.

Yet another, with slightly different meaning again, is:

```
target_map[found_elem->first] = found_elem->second;
```

Comment: `target_map.insert(*found_elem);` is enough. Then you can still check with the returned pair where and if the element was inserted.

Answer (score 0):

In current declaration

```
std::map<int, Obj> src_map
std::map<int, Obj> target_map
```

You can't have one Obj instance in memory connected to both maps. Either you remove Obj from `src_map` and put in `target_map` or change declaration to;

```
std::map<int, Obj*> src_map
std::map<int, Obj*> target_map
```

or any other pointer type (shared_ptr as suggested in comment), without this you will always have two independent objects in memory.